# AngularJS routing not working with a simple example

Tags: angularjs, routes

am new to angular js and learning. i tried a very simple example but it seems everything is right, but not working... I tried routing with two simple html files. The content of html should be placed on a ng-view div, when a userlist is clicked.. Please help in this... thanks in advance.. below is the code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page </title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

        myApp.config (function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/first.html',
                controller: 'FirstController'
            })

            .when('/Second', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
                controller: 'SecondController'
            });

        });

        myApp.controller('FirstController',function($scope){



        });

        myApp.controller('SecondController',function($scope){


        });     


    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
        <li> Home Page</li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Go to First Page  </a>    </li>
        <li> <a href="#/Second"> Go to Second Page  </li>       
        <h1> Main Page is here</h1>     
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the second `</a>`

```
  <ul>
        <li> Home Page</li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Go to First Page  </a>    </li>
        <li> <a href="#/Second"> Go to Second Page </a>  </li>       
        <h1> Main Page is here</h1>     
    </ul>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IdTbitdxNsGBmvjFEMDJ?p=preview)**

Comment: i tried with plnkr. its working.. but not working in my local system. i just copied your code and pasted it.. in chrome console am getting the following error  angular.js:10765XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Srini/Desktop/angtest/first.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765
angular.js:12520Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$compile/tpload?p0=first.html&p1=-1&p2=

Comment: issue is your html file not getting loaded

Comment: @srinivasan Routes only work with a web server, you get that error because you are running the file directly and not through a web server.